# SwiftUI TabbedView only shows first tab's content

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to build a `TabbedView` with the following simple code:

```
TabbedView {
    Text("Hello world")
        .tabItemLabel(Text("Hello"))
    Text("Foo bar")
        .tabItemLabel(Text("Foo"))
}
```

When running, both tabs are visible and enabled but the second tab's ("Foo") content is blank.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try adding tags:

```swift
    TabbedView {
        Text("Hello world")
            .tabItem { Text("Hello") }
            .tag(0)
        Text("Foo bar")
            .tabItem { Text("Foo") }
            .tag(1)
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't fix it on Xcode11Beta, Please see also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604914/tabbedview-using-swiftui-in-xcode11beta-11m336w

Comment: Thanks. How in the world did you figure out this fix?

Comment: .tabItemLabel is deprecated use .tabItem instead, please update your answer

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this by adding a `selection` state variable and passing that in for the selection:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var selection = 1

    var body: some View {
        TabbedView(selection: $selection) {
            Text("Tab 1!").tabItemLabel(
                Text("Tab 1")).tag(1)
            Text("Tab 2!").tabItemLabel(Text("Tab 2")).tag(2)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, tapping "Tab 2" will show "Tab 2!" on the screen, as opposed to a blank screen.

This was using Xcode 11.0 beta 2 (11M337n), macOS Catalina 10.15 Beta (19A487l).

Answer (score 1):

In the newest version you should use `TabView`:

```
   TabView {
        AnyView()
            .tabItem {
                Text("Label 1")
            }
        AnyView()
            .tabItem {
                Text("Label 2")
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode GM, TabbedView was renamed to [TabView](https://www.iosapptemplates.com/blog/swiftui/tabview-swiftui). So here's the right way to create a tab bar in SwiftUI now:

```swift
  TabView {
        Text("Hello world")
            .tabItem { Text("Hello") }
            .tag(0)
        Text("Foo bar")
            .tabItem { Text("Foo") }
            .tag(1)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, but you can't use an icon from SF Symbols, use the icons from //icons8.com or from another platform. or watch this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PfCU5h5z94

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body : some View {
        TabbedView {        
             Living_R()
                 .tabItemLabel(VStack {
                     Image("home")
                     Text("Home")
                 }).tag(0)
                    
             ContentView()
                 .tabItemLabel(VStack {
                     Image("search")
                     Text("Search")
                 }).tag(1)
                
             Text("Info")
                 .tabItemLabel(VStack {
                     Image("page")
                     Text("Doc")
                 }).tag(2)
        }   
    }    
}
```